# Python - Select rows based on cell elements(which are objects)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
message                                            topIntent
message1                       {"intent" : "UseCasePaymentArrangement","score" : "0.9899194717407227"}
message2                       {"intent" : "UseCaseReportAPayment","score" : "1"}
```

'topIntent' column is of type dict

From the above dataframe, **I want to filter out only the rows whos 'topIntent' columns, 'intent' field matches a particular value, say "UseCasePaymentArrangement"**.

**What I have tried:**

```
my_df.loc[(my_df.topIntent.intent == 'UseCasePaymentArrangement')]
```

The above obviously didnt work, I was getting **'intent' key error**

**Expected Output after filtering by topIntent columns 'intent' field(by 'UseCasePaymentArrangement'):**

```
message1                       {"intent" : "UseCasePaymentArrangement","score" : "0.9899194717407227"}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried, along with the expected output. For example, as you stated, what _should_ happen if the dict doesn't have _intent_?

Comment: @Chris, I have updated the question, please have a look

Comment: Are they `dict`? or `str`?

Comment: They are dict, sorry will update this in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
df[df['topIntent'].str.get('intent') == 'UseCasePaymentArrangement']
```

Output:

```
    message                                          topIntent
0  message1  {'intent': 'UseCasePaymentArrangement', 'score...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is annother way to do it using a list comprehension :

```
selected_intent = 'UseCasePaymentArrangement'

# We scan the df to get the matching indexes
indexes = [ind for x, ind in zip(df['topIntent'], df.index) 
        if 'intent' in list(x.keys()) and x['intent'] == selected_intent]

df.iloc[indexes]
```

---

Output :

```
    message                                          topIntent
0  message1  {'intent': 'UseCasePaymentArrangement', 'score...
```